# How to split a sequence file in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and try to read a sequence file and use it in a classification problem. Here is how I read the sequence file

```
  val tfidf = sc.sequenceFile("/user/hadoop/strainingtesting/tfidf-vectors", classOf[Text], classOf[VectorWritable])
```

I don't know how to split each line of the sequence file  by tab? i.e. how to get the Text value?

How can I use it for NAiveBayes classifier in Mllib?

Answer (score 0):

`sc.sequenceFile` returns an RDD of key/value tuples (Tuple2 objects in Scala). So if you just want an RDD of text, you can do a `map` to just pick up the keys in each line of the file.

```
val text = tfidf.map(_._1)
```

Naive Bayes expects an RDD of labeled vectors as input. And since there is no trivial way to convert your `VectorWritable` objects, maybe you can use mahout's vector dump utility to actually convert your sequence files into text files. And then read into spark.

```
mahout vectordump \
-i /user/hadoop/strainingtesting/tfidf-vectors \
-d /user/hadoop/strainingtesting/dictionary.file-\* \
-dt sequencefile -c csv -p true \
-o /user/hadoop/strainingtesting/tf-vectors.txt
```

And now read the text files into Spark using `sc.textFile` and perform necessary transformations.