# How to convert Mahout VectorWritable to Vector in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mahout, apache-spark-mllib

I have a `VectorWritable` (`org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable`) which is coming from a sequence file generated by Mahout and I would like to convert that into Vector (`org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors`) type is Spark. How can I do that in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have`RDD[(Text, VectorWritable)]` from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31734521/1560062).

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.iterableAsScalaIterableConverter

def mahoutToScala(v: org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable) =  {
    val scalaArray = v.get.all.asScala.map(_.get).toArray
    org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.dense(scalaArray)
}

rdd.map{ case (k, v) => (k.toString, mahoutToScala(v))}
```